# Xcode - ntoice touch with two image views with alpha

Tags: xcode

I have two images which are at the same position. But the image in front has a alpha channel on a position. I want to check if a third image is touching the image in the background with the alpha channel.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand the question - would you mind adding more detail, screenshots or code to help me understand?

Comment: I have an circle but at a position it is interruped. I want to find this area which is alpha in the image. I need a function which is called when a image is in this area :) thanks a lot

Comment: Is this a game? If so, many game engines (e.g. SpriteKit) have this sort of collision detection built-in. If you only have circles, you can check that (distance between centres of circles) > ( radius_circle1 + radius_circle2 ). For arbitrary shapes, it's more complicated.